# Alt property is empty in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

**My code**

```
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

**Returns** : Like this

```
<img width="650" height="366" src="https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112-650x366.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112-650x366.jpg 650w, https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112-300x169.jpg 300w, https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112-768x432.jpg 768w, https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112-1024x576.jpg 1024w, https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112-255x143.jpg 255w, https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112-1110x623.jpg 1110w, https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/5c1c7adb0c92110fd79f66aa_1545370331112.jpg 1500w" sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px">
```

Here the `alt`property value is empty.

But i need something to be filled for the `alt` property to fix the SEO bug.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in  your active themes functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes_add_alttopost', 20, 2);

function change_attachement_image_attributes_add_alttopost( $attr, $attachment ){
    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);

    // Get post type to check if it's post you can also add to any post type
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    if( $type != 'post' ){
        return $attr;
    }

    /// Get title
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;

    return $attr;
}
```

Comment: The above code sets the parent post title in the alt of image tag

Answer (score 0):

As Default the wordpress is getting uploaded image **alternative(alt)** content from the **"Media"** module.

**Example,** [image]

If the image source contains the alt content then the "the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' )" will return the alt text in DOM.